# Firefox android extension for Injecting javascript

Tags: android, firefox, mobile, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am attempting to develop a mobile Firefox extension that injects any javascript code to any pages. 
On desktop, you can use:

```
browser.tabs.executeScript()
```

to injects javascript to a page, however this method is not supported by the mobile Firefox browser.
I am just wondering if there is another way to inject javascript to pages for mobile extension.

Answer (score 0):

You may try OilCan (http://oilcan.jsharkey.org/). it allows inserting custom JavaScript for pages matching a URL pattern

Answer (score 0):

`browser.tabs.executeScript()` is supported on Android beginning in Firefox 54 which is currently on the Beta channel, scheduled to go to release in mid-June.

Comment: May I have reference ?